# Where is "chrome://browser//content//tabbrowser.js" file?

Tags: firefox

I got sometimes in some websites, *the script unresponsive error* : **unresponsive script I could not find anything on the internet about that specific error including **.

[Unresponsive script: chrome://browser/content/ext-utils.js:638](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1148460). **I am not using any extension.**

Comment: 4739 is the line of the js file that is hung

Comment: I believe that path is relative to the firefox cache, so it may or may not be on disk at all. check ~/.mozilla/firefox and ~/.cache/firefox . if not its just cached to memory, so you;ll have to use the dev tools to download it

Comment: The `chrome://` schema means this file is part of the Firefox browser. Changing it is infeasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wish to view the page, do it like this:

- Run Firefox
- Enter the following in the address bar :
  `chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.js`
- Right-click and use "Save page As..." to save it as `tabbrowser.js`
- Open the file with a text editor and position to line 4739.

Modifying this file is harder, since it is packaged into the `omni.ja`
file in the Firefox program folder and is replaced at every update.
So although you can unpack it using an unzip tool, edit files,
and put it back together, this is a very temporary fix.
It's also not officially supported by Mozilla, as you would expect.

Comment: I mean that modifying this file is something that Mozilla has documented but doesn't encourage, except for temporary fixes that haven't yet made it into the stable version.